# Hermite polynomial expression

Tags: hermite-polynomials

I want to expand $e^{-a^2 x^2}$ to a series with the hermite polynomials $H_{2n}(x)$ but i can't find out how. I've already expanded $x^{2n}$,$x^{2n+1}$ and $e^{ax}$ to a series of$H_n(x)$ but i can't relate them. Any help?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a relation ? How did you get the expansions ?

Comment: they are in the same book and usually this author connect's the exercises. for the first 2 i used a given formula for $x^n$ and for the last one i used the Hermite polynomial generator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is known that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x)H_n(y)}{n!}\left(\frac u 2\right)^n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} e^{\frac{2u}{1+u}x y-\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}(x-y)^2}$$
If we let $y=0$ we find that
$$\sqrt{1-u^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x)H_n(0)}{n!}\left(\frac u 2\right)^n= e^{-\frac{u^2}{1-u^2}x^2}$$
If we run the substitution $a^2 = \frac{u^2}{1-u^2}$ we can solve for $u$ and subsitute in to get a closed form for your series. Wikipedia cites [this source](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002152975), which is in German but provides the needed documents for free as far as I could tell. Note that you can probably clean this up a bit to be in terms of $H_{2n}(x)$, since the Hermite Numbers $H_n(0)$ are defined to be $0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: [+1] Excellent. Is there a connection with Gram-Charlier expansions ?

Comment: Great answer! Much appreciated.